# Generalized eigenvalue problem be converted to standard eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I have one question about convert the GEP to SEP

GEP: $Ax = \lambda Bx$, $A,B\in C^{n\times n}$.

Firstly, let $B$ to make a singular value decomposition. $B = U*S*W^H$.

Then, we have $S^{-1/2}*U^H*A*W*S^{-1/2}z=\lambda z$.

However, when I obtain the eigenvector $z$, I also want to compute the eigenvector x of $Ax = \lambda Bx$.

Is it correct that $x = W*S^{-1/2}z $ ? If correct, please tell me the reason.

If not correct, please tell me how to compute the eigenvector $x$ of $Ax = \lambda Bx$.

Thank you and I need help.
It is very important in my research.

Comment: Yes, it is. Replace $B$ with $US^{1/2}S^{1/2} W^H$. Aside: That approach is usually rather expensive. Usually one uses $B^{-1} A x = \lambda x$.

Comment: When B is close to singular matrix, if use $B^{-1}Ax=\lambda x$, the MATLAB will warn the computation of eigenvalue is not correct, However if I use the SVD  decomposition of $B$, then convert problem to $S^{-1/2}*U^H*A*W*S^{-1/2}$ for computing the eigenvalue. The MATLAB will not warn this computation. Can the SVD of $B$ reduce the error of $B^{-1}A$ ?

Comment: Yes, using the SVD approach is more stabile.